# How to breakdown json to sql

Tags: mysql, json, relational-database

I wanted to breakdown a json object to sql tables with relations. I am asking for help or any good advice, an example would be perfect. I am trying to write a script that extracts and loads complete json objects into sql tables. First i have to create a perfect sql table setup before i can start this process.

This is one of those millions objects i have.

```
 /* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("540449a4f59600af7d285075"),
  "leagues" : [{
      "name" : "Cassiopeia's Hunters",
      "tier" : "GOLD",
      "queue" : "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "21893177",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "JoKoksa",
          "division" : "III",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(5),
          "wins" : NumberLong(99),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : true,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(21893177)         <-----------
    }, {
      "name" : "Kayle's Patriots",
      "tier" : "BRONZE",
      "queue" : "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "TEAM-ffbaccc0-b8c0-11e2-b67a-782bcb497d6f",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "EloStechers",
          "division" : "II",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(64),
          "wins" : NumberLong(9),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : false,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(21893177)
    }, {
      "name" : "Cassiopeia's Infiltrators",
      "tier" : "BRONZE",
      "queue" : "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "TEAM-ffbaccc0-b8c0-11e2-b67a-782bcb497d6f",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "EloStechers",
          "division" : "II",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(60),
          "wins" : NumberLong(11),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : true,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(21893177)
    }],
  "summonerId" : NumberLong(21893177),
  "region" : "euw",
  "updatedAt" : NumberLong(1413669289)
}
```

the structure stops after `"id" : NumberLong(21893177)`. You can probably ignore whats coming after since its just the same structure. Thank you in advance! all i need is how would you build up the tables and pk/fk's, data types is not needed as I will figure that out myself. I am having hard times creating additional tables from entries to detailed playerinformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create for each subobject a seperate table. In each of these tables you will have a FK that matches the PK of the parent object.

So in your example you would have a table for the objects with the id as PK, the leagues as seperate table with id as PK and FK with the object id than the players table with PK id and FK with the id of the league etc.